# Python: changing element of a list at a random index

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, random

I'm working on a simple minesweeper game in python, and am trying to create a function that inserts mines into an empty board.

Note that the board is in the form of a list of lists, as so:

```
[[col, col, col...],[col,col,col...],[...],[...]...]
```

my function looks like this:

```
def insert_mines(NUM_MINES):
for mine in range(NUM_MINES):
    rand_row = randint(0, NUM_ROWS - 1)
    rand_col = randint(0, NUM_COLS - 1)
    if BOARD[rand_row][rand_col] == 'O':
        BOARD[rand_row][rand_col] = 'X'
        NUM_MINES = NUM_MINES - 1
    else:
        BOARD[rand_row][rand_col] = 'X'

print NUM_MINES
```

when I run it with num_mines = 96, it never prints zero, which is what it should print if all the mines have been inserted.

What could be the cause of this?

note that 'X' represents a mine and 'O' is just a board space with no mine.

Comment: By the way, the most uniform way to distribute mines is to put the required number of mines at the front of your grid, then shuffle the whole lot.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that after 96 iterations all empty space will be selected and replaced with mine, since sampling is done uniformly over the grid; i.e. the sampled indices might be repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to have zero printed is if

```
BOARD[rand_row][rand_col] == 'O'
```

for *every* iteration. Depending on the `NUM_ROWS` and `NUM_COLS` this may be surprisingly unlikely due to the ["birthday paradox"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

An easier way to make your board as suggested by Chris

```
cells = ['O'] * NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS
cells[:NUM_MINES] = ['X'] * NUM_MINES
random.shuffle(cells)
BOARD = [cells[i::NUM_ROWS] for i in range(NUM_ROWS)]
```

Comment: a much more elegant answer than mine. Thank you